# Системы генерации отчетов

Tags: sql-server, crystalreport

Изначально ставка делалась на ICONICS ReportWorx, но лицензия на данный продукт стоит очень больших денег. Сейчас стоит вопрос о выборе системы генерации отчетов. Данные берем исключительно из MSSQL SERVER.

Из требований: чтобы незнакомый с программированием человек смог создать свой шаблон, т.е. предполагает какой-нибудь визуальный конструктор. Ну и наверное цена. Одна лицензия не более 1.000 $.

Буду благодарен за мнения, кто чем пользуется и т.д.

p.s. гуглил и читал обзоры по сравнению систем, но хочется услышать о реальном использовании и подводных камнях. Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас уже есть MS SQL Server, то есть смысл использовать MS SQL Server Reporting Server (SSRS).

В принципе у всех систем отчетности редактор/принцип одинаков, так почему бы не использовать то, что уже есть?